Getting error on Sitecore Commerce 9.3, SXA
I am getting an error on Sitecore Commerce 9.3, SXA.
Server Error in '/' Application.
Illegal recursion detected: GetModel
Description: An unhandled exception occurred.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Illegal recursion detected: GetModel

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[InvalidOperationException: Illegal recursion detected: GetModel]
   Sitecore.Mvc.Common.RecursionPreventer..ctor(String title, Flag flag) +173
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering.GetModel() +73
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering.get_Model() +31
   Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Mvc.Wrappers.Rendering.get_Item() +35
 
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.9232.0


I've tried this solution but not working for me.
Sitecore Commerce 9.2 - sxa.storefront.com - Illegal recursion detected: GetModel
Appreciate any help!

An SXA site might fail to load for the first time with an unhandled exception. The website gets normally displayed after you have refreshed the page once or twice.
To resolve the issue, consider one of the following options:

Upgrade a Sitecore XP instance to Sitecore XP 10.0 and SXA 10.0.0 or later.

Download and install the latest cumulative hotfix compatible with the affected product version:

For Sitecore XP 9.2 and SXA 1.9.0, see KB1001753
For Sitecore XP 9.3 and SXA 9.3.0, see KB1001754



Reference:
https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0861591
Hope it helps!
